# SQL Server 2008 Express, need to copy a table from one server to another automatically

Tags: backup, remote, sql-server-2008, sql

We have 2 servers with SQL Server 2008 Express for IVR systems and one for our website. The website's database server is more accessible on our network. I would like to copy some tables from the other two servers to the website's database server for reporting purposes and to make it easier to lookup transactions. As you probably know, the paid version of SQL Server makes what I'm trying to do extremely easy, and the free version makes it difficult. So what I need is a tool or script that is free to either generate a backup or script that I can use to automatically copy the table to our other database every day. I looked at sqlpubwiz, but couldn't find out where to get it or how to install it (it seems to have only came with an old version of SQL Server 2005 Express I had).

Comment: It's not that it makes it difficult, its that Express doesn't have the SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out these free tools which uses windows scheduler to do backup in Express edition of sql server. [ExpressMaint](http://expressmaint.codeplex.com/) and [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/).

Comment: I've used those tools, but I really just want this single table synced, no the entire database.

Comment: Have you tried writing a script that will insert into your reporting tables and scheduling it using windows job scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqlcmd` or `osql` to script out the actions, then using Task Scheduler to run the script, may work for you.